# Номер недели по текущей дате

Tags: perl, datetime

Чтобы определить номер текущей недели в php  достаточно одной строчки

```
date("W", time());
```

Как сделать тоже самое на перле?
Нашел только пару примеров на несколько строк. Неужели нельзя как-то проще.

Comment: Почему в английском языке "car" всего из 3-х букв, а в русском слове "машина" в 2 раза больше букв? _Аналогия_ ясна? Советую не заморачиваться и скопировать те несколько строк.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -MTime::Piece -E '$t = localtime; say $t->week'
3
```

Answer (score 3):

можно воспользоваться функцией `strftime()` из пакета [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html). параметры и результат — те же:

```
$ perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%W", localtime;'
03
```